# How to pass paramters in dynamically created functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have created one form and form after submitting the value I want to show them in a table. In table I have one section where I want to delete or edit a particular user on a button. But when I am passing the id to that function I am getting error saying that refernece error occurred!

```js
function getEmployeeDetails() {
 for (var i = 0; i < userArray.length; i++) {
    var tr = "<tr>";

    tr +=
      "<td class='table-data'/td>" +
      userArray[i].id +
      "</td>" +
      "<td class='table-data'/td>" +
      userArray[i].name +
      "</td>" +
      "<td class='table-data'/td>" +
      userArray[i].email +
      "</td>" +
      "<td class='table-data'/td>" +
      userArray[i].gender +
      "</td>" +
      "<td class='table-data'/td>" +
      userArray[i].role +
      "</td>" +
      "<td class='table-data'/td>" +
      userArray[i].english +
      "</td>" +
      "<td class='table-data'/td>" +
      userArray[i].hindi +
      "</td>" +
      "<td class='table-data'/td>" +
      userArray[i].othersLang +
      "</td>" +
      "<td class='table-data'/td>" +
      userArray[i].description +
      "</td>" +
      "<td class='table-data'/td>" +
      "<button onclick='deleteUser( userArray[i].id )'>Delete</button> || <button onclick='editUser( userArray[i].id )'>Edit</button>" +
      "</td>" +
      "</tr>";

    tbody.innerHTML += tr;
  }
}

function deleteUser(id) {
  console.log("delteuser", typeof id, id);
}
function editUser(id) {
  console.log("edit", id);
}
```

Where I have made the mistakes?

Comment: You can inspect the page and check to figure out whats went wrong in that button..

Comment: First, your definitions for `<td>` are malformed, they are wrong-closed. Change your current `"<td class='table-data'/td>"` by  `'<td class="table-data">'`. Second, change the `onclick` attribute from `onclick='deleteUser( userArray[i].id )'` to `onclick='deleteUser(" + userArray[i].id + ")'`. And third, a better approach to avoid expose public functions, is to register listeners privately, using [`element.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) or a crossbrowser fallback with `element.onclick`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the string concatenation you are using in the onClick event.

You can use a backtick character instead.
Copy-paste and check the below code.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table id="table"></table>
    <script>
      getEmployeeDetails();
      function getEmployeeDetails() {
        let userArray = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }];
        var tr = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < userArray.length; i++) {
          tr +=
            `<td class="table-data">
              <button onclick="deleteUser(` +
                      userArray[i].id +
                      `)">Delete</button> || <button onclick="editUser( ` +
                      userArray[i].id +
                    `)">Edit</button>
             </td>`;
        }
        document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = tr;
      }
      function deleteUser(id) {
        console.log("delteuser", typeof id, id);
      }
      function editUser(id) {
        console.log("edit", id);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Souradip. Please accept the answer if it worked in your case. It might help others who land up here.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
  <button onclick='deleteUser( userArray[i].id )'>
```

To something like

```
 <button onclick='deleteUser('+userArray[i].id+')'>
```

In your current attempt you are not inserting the value of userArray[i].id but the variable userArray[i].id which is kind of nonsense.

Same story with the editUser function

Comment: It is not working properly. When I run the "getEmployeeDetails()" function it executes both functions and console out the id. But when I click the buttons from the created table separately, It is not showing any output. It actually executes both the functions before I call them

Comment: Then there is another error in your markup or js , there is no logical explanation why it should execute the functions before clicked.